# Mezzanine Blog Page Title not Displayed

Tags: html, django, blogs, mezzanine

I am working on a client's Django/Mezzanine website that has got some strange issue that I just can't seem to figure out. On the blog page (template of blog_post_list.html) I cannot get the meta title of the page to display, meaning

```
{% block meta_title %}
{{ blog_page.title }}  
{% endblock %}
```

produces no output in the resulting html. The same holds for the meta description, but I am not worried about it as much. The strange thing is that it seems to work just fine for individual blog entries, as well as all the other pages on the website, except the blog list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there was a bit of confusion involved: I thought blog_page.title was a standard variable in mezzanine, apparently it is not, it was a custom model created by the previous developer. Since I have basically only the templates and a dump of the DB, it does not appear to be possible to restore the original model for blog_page class, so I simply solved it by supplying a meta title manually in the blog_post_list template.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is displayed in Django template if you render not existing variable or variable value is None.

First test if `{{ blog_page }}` renders anything. If it doesn't check if `blog_page` is in your template context.

You can debug template's context by writing simple custom templatetag, e.g.:

templates/your_template.html:

```
{% load pdb from debug %}

{% block meta_title %}
    {% pdb %}
    {{ blog_page.title }}  
{% endblock %}
```

templatetags/debug.py:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(name='pdb', takes_context=True)
def pdb(context, *args, **kwargs):
    import ipdb;
    ipdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: Hi niekas, {{ blog_page }} does not render anything, although the changes in the blog list template are reflected fine. How do I go about checking if it is in the template context?

Comment: I got three warnings in the trace, the most relevant would be: '/home/user/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/blog/models.py:71: UserWarning: blog_post.category_list in templates is deprecateduse blog_post.categories.all which are prefetched
  warn("blog_post.category_list in templates is deprecated"'